# Meta-analysis in metafor package with within-subjects standard error?

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, meta-analysis

I am conducting a meta-analysis with metafor in R. For the majority of articles, I managed to extract **means** and **standard deviations**, which I need for the escalc function to calculate an effect size.

However, many of the articles only provide means and within-subject standard error.

My questions: 1. is there a way to calculate standard deviation or standard error of the mean from the within subject standard error? 
2. is there a way to calculate an effect size from only means and within subject standard error in metafor?

thanks!

Comment: Can you clarify what the design of the studies is so that it is clearer what within subject standard error means?

Comment: Instead of standard error you could weigh studies by sample size, as long as the measurement approach is similar across studies.

Comment: answer to @mdewey 
the studies are all experiments (cognitive psychology) with 2 levels of manipulations (high-reward distractors vs low reward distractors), the dependent measure is response time. 
within subject standard error: because basically no articles provide basic descriptives such as M and SD, I used a plot digitizer to read descriptives. in these plots, sometimes, the error bars represent within subject standard errors (meaning, standard error of the mean, corrected for between-subject variability -- I think).

Comment: Well, if you have the standard error and the sample size you can back-calculate the standard deviation so I am still not sure what you are missing here.